# How Can I Place Two TextBox(input field) side by side in a fieldset in cakephp?

Tags: cakephp

I have a form in a .ctp file. I want to Place Two TextBox(input field) side by side in a fieldset.I have tried This Code:

```
Form->inputs(array('OrderItem.0.title'=>array('label'=>'OrderItemTitle/Name','div'=>array('class'=>'modified_size')),'OrderItem.0.weight'=>array('div'=>array('class'=>'modified_size'))));?>
```

--> I have already define a class in cake.generic.css like:

```
.modified_size{float:left !important;width:45%;display:inline-block;clear:none!important}
```

-->But its doesn't works. Please give me advice and solution in this matter.

Answer (score 1):

Just try using `input` instead of `inputs`

```
echo $this->Form->input('OrderItem.0.title', array(
    'label' => 'OrderItemTitle/Name',
    'class'=>'modified_size',
    'after' =>  $this->Form->input('OrderItem.0.weight', array(
        'class'=>'modified_size',
        'div' => false
    ))
));
```

Hope this will help you.